# enum element 'value' cannot be referenced as an instance member

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, xcode8

Can anyone please help me to figure out this problem?
Actually I am having this error while archiving the build. when I run the build on my device I get no error.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot)

 print(Snapshot.value)


})
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked perfectly. Just added "in" after (Snapshot).